# Xamarin: How to avoid internal ListView from change its content size when showing keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im creating this content page:

```cs
Content = new StackLayout()
{
    Spacing = 0,
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    Children = {
        (listView = new ListView
        {
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            ItemsSource = listItems,
            ItemTemplate = new MyDataTemplateSelector(userName),
            BackgroundColor = Constants.Cor_ChatFundo
        }),
        (grid = new Grid
        {
            RowSpacing = 1,
            ColumnSpacing = 2,
            Padding = new Thickness(5),
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) }
            },
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(40) }
            }
        })
    }
};

grid.Children.Add(sendMessageEntry = new Entry
{
    FontSize = 18,
    HeightRequest = 30,
    Placeholder = "Type here...",
    Keyboard = Keyboard.Chat
}, 0, 0);


grid.Children.Add(buttonSend = new Button
{
    Text = "Send"
}, 1, 0);
```

I'm using a modified version of the KeyboardOverlapRenderer to move the entire page UP when the keyboard is shown.

The modified version of the KeyboardOverlapRenderer is to handle the suggestion bar above the iOS8 keyboard... the original version doesn't handle that.

The KeyboardOverlapRenderer class:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using CoreGraphics;
using EficienciaEnergetica.iOS.KeyboardOverlap;
using System.Diagnostics;
using EficienciaEnergetica.ContentPages;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(KeyboardOverlapRenderer))]
namespace EficienciaEnergetica.iOS.KeyboardOverlap
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class KeyboardOverlapRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        Rectangle initialViewState;


        NSObject _keyboardShowObserver;
        NSObject _keyboardHideObserver;
        private bool _pageWasShiftedUp;
        private double _activeViewBottom;
        private bool _isKeyboardShown;

        public static void StaticInit()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            Debug.WriteLine("Keyboard Overlap plugin initialized {0}", now);
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            var page = Element as ContentPage;

            if (page != null)
            {
                var contentScrollView = page.Content as ScrollView;

                if (contentScrollView != null)
                    return;

                initialViewState = Element.Bounds;

                RegisterForKeyboardNotifications();
            }
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

            UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications();
        }

        void RegisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            if (_keyboardShowObserver == null)
                _keyboardShowObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, OnKeyboardShow);
            if (_keyboardHideObserver == null)
                _keyboardHideObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, OnKeyboardHide);
        }

        void UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            _isKeyboardShown = false;
            if (_keyboardShowObserver != null)
            {
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(_keyboardShowObserver);
                _keyboardShowObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardShowObserver = null;
            }

            if (_keyboardHideObserver != null)
            {
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(_keyboardHideObserver);
                _keyboardHideObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardHideObserver = null;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnKeyboardShow(NSNotification notification)
        {
            if (!IsViewLoaded)
                return;

            _isKeyboardShown = true;
            var activeView = View.FindFirstResponder();

            if (activeView == null)
                return;

            var keyboardFrame = UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(notification);
            var isOverlapping = activeView.IsKeyboardOverlapping(View, keyboardFrame);

            if (!isOverlapping)
                return;

            if (isOverlapping)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(keyboardFrame);
                _activeViewBottom = activeView.GetViewRelativeBottom(View);
                ShiftPageUp(keyboardFrame.Height, _activeViewBottom);
            }
        }

        private void OnKeyboardHide(NSNotification notification)
        {
            if (!IsViewLoaded)
                return;

            _isKeyboardShown = false;
            var keyboardFrame = UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(notification);

            if (_pageWasShiftedUp)
                ShiftPageDown(keyboardFrame.Height, _activeViewBottom);
        }

        private void ShiftPageUp(nfloat keyboardHeight, double activeViewBottom)
        {
            var pageFrame = initialViewState;// Element.Bounds;

            var newY = pageFrame.Y + CalculateShiftByAmount(pageFrame.Height, keyboardHeight, activeViewBottom);

            Element.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(pageFrame.X, newY,
                pageFrame.Width, pageFrame.Height));

            _pageWasShiftedUp = true;
        }

        private void ShiftPageDown(nfloat keyboardHeight, double activeViewBottom)
        {
            Element.LayoutTo(initialViewState);
            _pageWasShiftedUp = false;
        }

        private double CalculateShiftByAmount(double pageHeight, nfloat keyboardHeight, double activeViewBottom)
        {
            return (pageHeight - activeViewBottom) - keyboardHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is when editing the entry. In iOS it shows the keyboard, but the content of the internal listview seems to allocate an empty space for the keyboard also, and it is possible to scroll down the list more than the elements that are inside it.

Is it possible to disable the listview keyboard notification behaviour in this situation? The ListView is not the main component in this page.

Comment: "... but the content of the internal listview seems to allocate an empty space for the keyboard also" -the issue seems to be in your modified version of the KeyboardOverlapRenderer. Could you share that code?

Comment: I put the code above. I believe this is not the problem, because the keyboard overlap code interacts with the Page not with the content. And the listview is a inner content (inside the stacklayout).

Comment: Place a breakpoint on this line ‘activeViewBottom = activeView.GetViewRelativeBottom(View);’ and make sure it is hit only once

Comment: It is called once in a keyboard without the suggestion bar, and called twice in a keyboard with suggestion bar.

I checked the GetViewRelativeBottom content, it does not modify the view, It returns just the top Y position + view Height.

Comment: Hmm I can’t think of anything then. Try to play around the vertical options in the app, editing the values to see if anything works, including of the list view cell.

Comment: ok, thanks you for trying to help.

I believe it is an internal listview implementation issue. The thing I thought that could help me is a way that can turn on/off the listview keyboard notification behaviour... Because the current implementation does not check if the listview is the main container or a child container of the page...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me!
Set lv.HeightRequest on the entry focus!
Seems to be

Comment: and have to set always a diferent value!
In my case i do it:
c=c*(-1);
lv.HightRequest = lv.Height + (c);

Comment: If your post was incomplete, you should click [edit] to finish it off, not add more in the comments.